# Generic Class Polymorphisim

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, polymorphism

If I have the following:

```
public abstract class Parameter<T>  
{
    protected T value;

    public virtual T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    protected Parameter(T startingValue)
    {
        value = startingValue;
    }
}

public class FloatParameter : Parameter<float> 
{
    public FloatParameter(float startingValue) : base(startingValue){}
}

public class IntParameter : Parameter<int> 
{
    public override int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value > 100 ? 100 : value; }
    }

    public IntParameter(int startingValue) : base (startingValue) {}
}
```

Is there any way to create some `List<Parameter>` that can contain any of the derived types? For example, something like:

```
// no type specified in Parameter
List<Parameter> storedParameters = new List<Parameter>(); 
storedParameters.Add(new FloatParameter(2f));
storedParameters.Add(new IntParameter(7));

foreach(Parameter p in storedParameters)
{
    DoSomethingWithValue(p.Value);
}
```

Or, alternatively, if this implementation is flawed, is there a better way to do this? What I have here feels slightly naive.

Comment: why you want to hold mango in list of oranges?

Comment: Well, what type should `Value` have in your example?

Comment: The problem with this implementation is the two type you are trying to use. Int and float are struct which means once you have assigned T to one of them you cannot add the other.

Comment: Can you add code for `DoSomethingWithValue`?

Comment: `DoSomethingWithValue` is a generic method that does run time type checking on the value. And `Value` should have the same type as specified by the generic. so `FloatParameter`'s `Value` property should return a float.

Comment: If `DoSomethingWithValue` do run-time type checking it should be implemented polymorphically inside each class in hierarchy.

Comment: it's part of a library that I did not write. It accepts a few different data types and formats them as an OSC message to be sent over a UDP port. If the type passed in is not one of the accepted types then it throws an error.

Comment: So does it accept an object? Is it generic? Does it have many overloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I see to manage such case is to have and Interface that you use to manage the generic types, something like this should work:

```
public interface IParameter
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public abstract class Parameter<T>
{
    protected T value;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    protected Parameter(T startingValue)
    {
        value = startingValue;
    }
}

public class FloatParameter : Parameter<float>, IParameter
{
    public FloatParameter(float startingValue) : base(startingValue) { }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

public class IntParameter : Parameter<int>, IParameter
{
    public IntParameter(int startingValue) : base(startingValue) { }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Ont his case you would be able to create a List of the Interface IParameter and add there specific instances:

```
 var list = new List<IParameter>();
 list.Add(new FloatParameter(1F));
 list.Add(new IntParameter(1));

 foreach (var item in list)
 {
      item.DoSomething();
 }
```

Comment: This is a really nice way to do this. However, can you think of a way that would allow for me to access the properties of the `Parameter` object from the `item` foreach variable?

Comment: @DannyHerbert That's not possible.  The compiler can't know what specific types are stored in the list (in fact, this could depend on user input that isn't available until the program is running).  So there's no way it can provide access to properties on the more specific types because it can't know that they'll actually be there.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add nongeneric interface. Here is an example:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        try
        {
            List<IParameter> storedParameters = new List<IParameter>();
            storedParameters.Add(new FloatParameter(2f));
            storedParameters.Add(new IntParameter(7));

            foreach (IParameter p in storedParameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public interface IParameter
{
    object value { get; }
}

public class Parameter<T> : IParameter
{
    public object value { get; protected set; }

    public virtual T Value
    {
        get { return (T)value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }


    protected Parameter(T startingValue)
    {
        value = startingValue;
    }
}

public class FloatParameter : Parameter<float>
{
    public FloatParameter(float startingValue) : base(startingValue){ }
}

public class IntParameter : Parameter<int>
{
    public override int Value
    {
        get { return (int)value; }
        set { this.value = value > 100 ? 100 : value; }
    }

    public IntParameter(int startingValue) : base (startingValue) { }
}
```

Comment: Storing a primitive `T` in an `object` field will require boxing/unboxing whenever it's accessed via the `T Value` property. Also, you can use the same property name if you explicitly implement `IParameter`.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the value to an object you will be able to set the value to whatever type you like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // no type specified in Parameter
        var storedParameters = new List<ParameterBase>();
        storedParameters.Add(new FloatParameter(3.5F));
        storedParameters.Add(new IntParameter(7));

        foreach (var p in storedParameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class ParameterBase
{
    protected object value;

    public virtual object Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
}

public class FloatParameter : ParameterBase
{
    public FloatParameter(float value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class IntParameter : ParameterBase
{
    public IntParameter(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

UPDATED: Use object instead of dynamic and removed ValueType as suggested by @Pieter Witvoet

Comment: Why don't you use `object`? `dynamic` is primarily meant for dynamic language interop, and comes with additional costs (late binding).

Comment: Thanks @Pieter Witvoet, I've updated the code to use object :)

Comment: Another thing: why must the type be set separately? That can easily be abused: `Value = "hello"; ValueType = typeof(int);`. But why store it at all? `IntParameter` should always return `typeof(int)`, so why not make the base class property abstract, and override it in each derived `Parameter` class? Note how there's very little difference between `IntParameter` and `FloatParameter` - you could use a single generic `Parameter<T>` class instead (where `ValueType` returns `typeof(T)`, of course).

Comment: It was there for illustration that the type being set was of type int or float.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do it.

What you are trying to do is to have an interface (or base class) that expose a property of an undefined type, to be able to then retrieve that value and dispatch it dynamically to the proper override of `DoSomethingWithValue`.

What you are after is achievable defining the property as `dynamic`, instead of using generics.

```
public class Parameter
{
    protected dynamic value;

    public dynamic Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    public Parameter(dynamic startingValue)
    {
        value = startingValue;
    }
}

public class MyStuff {
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        List<Parameter> storedParameters = new List<Parameter>();
        storedParameters.Add(new Parameter(2f));
        storedParameters.Add(new Parameter(7));

        foreach (Parameter p in storedParameters)
        {
            DoSomethingWithValue(p.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you should look into implementing a `Double dispatch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by defining a common interface and using the visitor pattern.

```
public interface IParameterVisitor
{
    void VisitInt(int value);
    void VisitFloat(float value);
}

public interface IParameter
{
    void Accept(IParameterVisitor visitor);
}
```

The previous implementation has to be modified a bit:

```
public abstract class Parameter<T> : IParameter
{
    protected T value;

    public virtual T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    protected Parameter(T startingValue)
    {
        value = startingValue;
    }

    public abstract void Accept(IParameterVisitor visitor);
}
```

`FloatParameter` will `VisitFloat`, and `IntParameter` will `VisitInt`

```
public class FloatParameter : Parameter<float>
{
    public FloatParameter(float startingValue) : base(startingValue) { }
    public override void Accept(IParameterVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitFloat(this.value);
    }
}

public class IntParameter : Parameter<int>
{
    public override int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value > 100 ? 100 : value; }
    }

    public override void Accept(IParameterVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitInt(this.value);
    }

    public IntParameter(int startingValue) : base(startingValue) { }
}
```

And our visitor for example:

```
public class MyVisitor : IParameterVisitor
{
    public void VisitInt(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Visiting an int: {value}");
    }

    public void VisitFloat(float value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Visiting a float: {value}");
    }
}
```

Finally, the usage:

```
var parameters = 
    new List<IParameter> {new FloatParameter(0.5f), new IntParameter(1)};
var visitor = new MyVisitor();
foreach (IParameter parameter in parameters) {
   parameter.Accept(visitor);
}
```